# println does not print the expected value

Tags: java, concatenation, conditional-operator, println

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{

    String x = null;
    String y = "10";
    String z = "20";

    System.out.println("This my first out put "+x==null?y:z);

    x = "15";

    System.out.println("This my second out put "+x==null?y:z);

}
```

My output is:

```
20
20
```

But I'm expecting this:

```
This my first out put 10
This my second out put 20
```

Could someone explain me why I'm getting "20" as output for both println calls?

Comment: Sumit Singh's answer explains why the output is like it is. The reason is operator precedence, see [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.out.println("This my first out put "+x==null?y:z);`  will be executed like

`("This my first out put "+x)==null?y:z` which is never going to be true. So, it will display `z` value.

For example:

```
int x=10;
int y=20;
System.out.println(" "+x+y); //display 1020
System.out.println(x+y+" "); //display 30
```

For above scenario, operation performed **left to right**.

As, you said, you are expecting this:

```
This my first output 10
```

For this, you need little change in your code. Try this

`System.out.println("This my first output " + ((x == null) ? y : z));`

Comment: evaluation of expressions in Java is NOT always left to right.  It takes account of operator precedence!

Comment: @StephenC i know, but i was talking for this scenario only. Rather, it will increase more confusion, i removed ALWAYS from my statement. I believe, now it will be OK. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
System.out.println("This my first out put "+ (x==null?y:z));
```

Comment: This will indeed generate the desired output, but does not answer OPs question: _Could someone explain me **why** I'm getting "20" as output for both println calls?_

Answer (score 1):

you need to try:

```
System.out.println("This my first out put "+(x==null?y:z));
x = "15";
System.out.println("This my second out put "+(x==null?y:z));
```